# prepopulate Html.TextBoxFor in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'n new at this, so apologies if this isn't explanatory enough. I want to prepopulate a field in a form in asp.net mvc 3. This works;

```
@Html.TextBox("CompName", null, new { @value = ViewBag.CompName })
```

But when I want to prepopulate it with a value and send that value to my model, like this;

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comps.CompName, null, new { @value = ViewBag.CompName })
```

It won't work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So, I would suggest is to move to using viewmodels rather than the ViewBag.  I made a folder in my project called ViewModels and then under there make some subfolders as appropriate where I put my various viewmodels.

If you create a viewmodel class like so:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string CompName { get; set; }
}
```

then in your controller action you can create one of those and populate it, maybe from some existing model pulled from a database.  By setting that `CompName` property in the viewmodel, it'll have that value in your view. And then your view can look something like this:

```
@model MyNamespace.ViewModels.MyViewModel

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompName)
```

or `@Html.TextBoxFor` would work too.

Then back in your controller action on the post, you've got something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel viewModel)
{
   ...
   // do whatever you want with viewModel.CompName here, like persist it back
   // to the DB
   ...
}
```

Might be that you use something like automapper to map your models and viewmodels but you could certainly do that manually as well, though the whole lefthand/righthand thing gets quite tedious.

Makes things much easier if you do it this way and isn't much work at all.

---

**Update**

But, if you *really* want to pass that value in view the ViewBag, you could do this:

In your controller action:

```
ViewBag.CompName = "Some Name";
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Comps.CompName, new {@Value = ViewBag.CompName})
```

And that'll pre-populate the textbox with "Some Name".

I'd still go with the viewmodel approach, but this seems to work well enough.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply itsmatt. The viewbag is in my get-enter competition action and takes the name from my 'Competition' model (there is also a CompetitionEntry model(. It's so I can display the name of the competition on top of the entry form. In my competition entry model I have a navigation property 'public virtual Competition Competitions'. I thought that there would be an easy ay to pre-populate the CompetitionEntry.CompName TextBox with what's in the viewbag. I don't want to go changing my models at this stage to be honest, do you know of a way to do this in the view? Thanks again.

Comment: Dan, see my update at the end of my answer.  Seems to work well enough in my test project.

Comment: I won't get to try this for an hour or so, I'll write back when I do. Thanks for all you help matt!

Comment: Hi matt, that worked, but now whe I submit the form nothing is entered into the database. when I check all fields are blank. I'll have to so some investigating..

Comment: So, I'm sure you are checking this but are the fields filled in when they get back to the controller action or are they blank there?

Comment: I have, if I have 'disabled = "disabled"' as a value in my Html.TextBoxFor  everything but the CompName goes through, if I don't it's the opposite. I think I'm actually getting somewhere, I'll comment back in a little while. I'll be marking this as answer anyway as you got mr further along and basically answered what I asked. Strange stuff!

Comment: So I fixed it by adding a CompName property to my CompetitionEntry model and passing the ViewBag value into it instead of through the navigation property CompetitionEntries.Comps.CompName. So I get the CompName from my Competition model through it's id in my Get action and pass it to CompNmae in CompEntries through the viewbag. Seems a bit old school, but hey, that's mvc! I think if I just used a viewmodel like you said it would have worked, but I still think this is strange behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

From your controller, if you pass a model initialized with default values using one of the `View(...)` method overloads that accepts a model object, these values will be used by the view when rendered. You won't need to use the `@value = ...` syntax.