# empty string returns null for textboxfor mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html.textboxfor

In the problem [prepopulate Html.TextBoxFor in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337520/prepopulate-html-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc-3) you can see an answer in which the following piece of code works correctly.

```
ViewBag.CompName = "Some Name";
```

Then in your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model =>model.Comps.CompName, new {@Value = ViewBag.CompName})
```

However, when the textbox gets the initial value of an empty string "", it seems to post a value of null for this textbox.

```
ViewBag.CompName = "";
```

This sends a null value instead of an empty string.

Is there any way of returning an empty string instead of null?

Comment: while adding in `ViewBag`, you can add `string.empty` instead of `ViewBag.CompName` if it is null

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is expected behavior. Try using `DisplayFormat` attribute.

`[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull=false)]` on top of `CompName` property in your model.

[See Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.convertemptystringtonull%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

For Example:-

```
[DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
public string CompName
{
    get { return _compName; }
    set { _compName= value; }
}
```